# How can I get the location of a composable inside of a another composable with jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Let's say I want to show an overlay on top of another composable with multiple views. This overlay needs to know the location of views inside the view it is overlaying. Obviously the simple way is to hardcode the location but lets assume the view is more complex or that its location might depend on many other things how can I say assign the view an ID and then say where on the screen is this ID located? Or maybe this is not possible.

```
ConstraintLayoutDemo()
// Get the location of the blue square thats inside of ConstraintLayoutDemo()
```

```
@Composable
fun ConstraintLayoutDemo() {
    ConstraintLayout(modifier = Modifier.size(200.dp)) {
        val (redBox, blueBox, yellowBox, text) = createRefs()

        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .size(50.dp)
            .background(Color.Red)
            .constrainAs(redBox) {})

        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .size(50.dp)
            .background(Color.Blue)
            .constrainAs(blueBox) {
                top.linkTo(redBox.bottom)
                start.linkTo(redBox.end)
            })

        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .size(50.dp)
            .background(Color.Yellow)
            .constrainAs(yellowBox) {
                bottom.linkTo(blueBox.bottom)
                start.linkTo(blueBox.end, 20.dp)
            })

        Text("Hello World", modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(text) {
            top.linkTo(parent.top)
            start.linkTo(yellowBox.start)
        })

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Modifier.onGloballyPositioned{} to get position of a Composable inside parent, root  Composable or root with status bar height added using

```
val positionInParent: Offset = it.positionInParent()
val positionInRoot: Offset = it.positionInRoot()
val positionInWindow: Offset = it.positionInWindow()
```

In Compose parent's top left is counted as zero. If a Composable is aligned to top left of parent position is returned as Offset(0,0). I slightly modified your function to show how it changes.

[image]

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun ConstraintLayoutDemo() {

    var positionText by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    Column {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(50.dp))
        ConstraintLayout(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(start = 20.dp)
                .size(200.dp)
                .border(2.dp, Color.Green)
        ) {
            val (redBox, blueBox, yellowBox, text) = createRefs()

            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .size(50.dp)
                .background(Color.Red)
                .constrainAs(redBox) {})

            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .onGloballyPositioned {
                    val positionInParent: Offset = it.positionInParent()
                    val positionInRoot: Offset = it.positionInRoot()
                    val positionInWindow: Offset = it.positionInWindow()
                    positionText =
                        "positionInParent: $positionInParent\n" +
                                "positionInRoot: $positionInRoot\n" +
                                "positionInWindow: $positionInWindow"
                }
                .size(50.dp)
                .background(Color.Blue)

                .constrainAs(blueBox) {
                    top.linkTo(redBox.bottom)
                    start.linkTo(redBox.end)
                })

            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .size(50.dp)
                .background(Color.Yellow)
                .constrainAs(yellowBox) {
                    bottom.linkTo(blueBox.bottom)
                    start.linkTo(blueBox.end, 20.dp)
                })

            Text("Hello World", modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(text) {
                top.linkTo(parent.top)
                start.linkTo(yellowBox.start)
            })

        }

        Text(positionText)
    }
}
```

If you add Modifier.onGloballyPositioned to red you will get results as

[image]

Comment: I was hoping for a solution that would not require modifying the thing I am trying to watch but at this time I guess this is the best solution.